# Git merge after fetch - how, exactly?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-fetch

I've read from various sources that it's usually a better idea to fetch *then* merge rather than simply pull as it allows for finer control.  That said, I've yet to find actually how to do it.  Case in point:

There was a small change made to some of the code in one of my GitHub repository's master branch.  I was able to fetch it, but I don't know how to actually merge the differences in with *my* local master branch.  `git branch` lists all of the local branches I have, but nothing indicating anything to merge to.

So, is it just something like `git merge master` or `git merge origin/master`?  What am I missing?

Comment: If you're working on the master branch anyway, there's no point in not doing `git pull`, since `git pull` is just an alias for `git fetch && git merge origin/master`

Comment: Since you're just learning git, have you considered working on a branch?  They're really easy & disposable, too.   I've found that it's just easiest to just always work on a local topical branch, then , rebase to master, and finally push.

Comment: I do that, but if I want to keep my own master up-to-date as I'm working on my own feature in another branch, I need to fetch/pull from origin/master.  I was just wondering about the actual command(s) to do it.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`git merge origin/master` should work.  Since `master` is usually a tracking branch, you could also do `git pull` from that branch and it will do a fetch & merge for you.

If you have local changes on your `master` that aren't reflected on `origin`, you might want `git rebase origin/master` to make sure your commits are 'on top'.

Comment: Do I need to `git rebase origin/master` before `git merge orgin/master`? I'm asking only for the case when I have local changes on `master` that aren't reflected on `origin`.

Comment: You need to do one or the other, not both.  Which to choose depends on the outcome you're after, but `rebase` is usually what you want.

Answer (score 18):

I typically do this:

```
git merge --ff-only @{u}
```

Which says, "only do a fast-forward merge from the upstream tracking branch."  It's nice because if it fails, then I know I introduced something on `master` that is not upstream.  I have that aliased to `ff`, just to make it easier to type.

If there are changes, and you simply want to merge them, you can do:

```
git merge @{u}
```

Which will merge in the upstream branch.  However, if you'd like a cleaner history (and avoid the "Merging 'origin/master' into 'master'" commits, then you might want to consider rebasing instead:

```
git rebase @{u}
```

Of course, you can use `origin/master` instead of `@{u}` in any of these examples.

Answer (score 10):

The command

```
git pull $some_url
```

is equivalent to

```
git fetch $some_url
git merge FETCH_HEAD
```

See also the [git-pull(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html) man page for details, especially the first two paragraphs of the description.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch a specific branch:
`1. git fetch <branch URL><branch name>`

```
2. git pull = git fetch + git merge
```

`3(a). git merge origin/master` 
The origin/master and master branches now point to the same commit, and you are synchronized with the upstream developments.

**(OR)**

`3(b). git merge FETCH_HEAD`

Answer (score 0):

Doing a fetch and then immediately doing a merge is essentially just more typing for you. The important benefit that you receive from separating the two commands is that you can examine what you've pulled down before applying it to your working tree. You can check out the log of what has changed with this:

`git log origin/master`

and see the diffs that will be applied as well with the following:

`git diff origin/master`

If everything looks good, then you can merge the full thing, or select parts of what you fetched.